# Getting "Element is no longer valid" error while executing the below the code

Tags: java, selenium

I am new to Selenium. Getting

> org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no longer valid (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

error while running the below the code.

Expectation: while loop should resume once the method "changdrawer" returned true. Please help me if any correction is needed in my code.

```
public class ManageTaskList {

    public void CheckRequestType() throws InterruptedException
    {

        //Switching the driver to TaskList frame
        LaunchBrowser.driver.switchTo().frame("taskList");

        boolean dateFlag=false;
        String date = "06/12";

        WebElement table = LaunchBrowser.driver.findElement(By.id("dataTable"));
        List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
        Iterator<WebElement> i = rows.iterator();
        System.out.println("Table has following content");
        while(i.hasNext())
        {
            WebElement row=i.next();
            List<WebElement> columns= row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
            Iterator<WebElement> j = columns.iterator();
                while(j.hasNext())
                { 
                    WebElement column = j.next();


                    String ColumnValues=column.getText();
                    //System.out.println("ColumnValues" + ColumnValues);

                    if (ColumnValues.contains(date))
                    {
                         System.out.println("Date confirmed" +ColumnValues );
                        dateFlag = true;
                    }


                    if (ColumnValues.contentEquals("Issue Change Drawer") && dateFlag==true)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Found Change Drawer");
                        dateFlag=false;
                        column.click();
                        ChangeDrawer();
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    }



            }

    }
    public boolean ChangeDrawer() 
    {

        // Issue Change Drawer
        LaunchBrowser.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/div[3]/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/input")).click();
        LaunchBrowser.driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        return true;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the changeDrawer method (that is, a click on the element) causes the page to refresh, or even the table elements to change, even if you end up having a WebElement that still matches your selector (in this case, rows), you are still holding a reference to the "old" object, which doesn't exist anymore in the page.

You would need to call the findElement/s method again to refresh the WebElement if that is the case.

Comment: Do I need to refresh   'table' web element ? if so , do i need to rerun this method again? please share the sample code to refresh the page

Comment: StaleElementException is thrown when you are trying to interact with a WebElement that is no longer on the page or has changed. You don't want to refresh the page, but the element that is raising the StaleElementException. I don't know which one it is, you need to debug your code to find which is the element that is throwing the exception, then use findElement to "refresh" it.